# looking for algorithm to find boundary of color region

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I have a canvas with image drawn to it.

When the user clicks on the image, I need to find the color region that the user clicked on. A region is defined as a set of 4-way connected pixels with the same color as the pixel that was clicked on.

I need the region in a form that I could use to set a clipping path on the canvas, so that I could fill the area with, say, a gradient, etc.

Are there efficient algorithms for finding a boundary? Something more optimal than flood fill algorithms (I do not need to fill, I just need to find a path around my region).

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is not a single boundary, e.g. clicking on a torus, or on the cheeks of a [smiley face](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml)?

Comment: for my application it would be sufficient to get a path describing the outer region, unless obtaining a set of paths that describe both the outer and the inner regions as well is not much more expensive. I suspect that I need some sort of pixel labeling algorithm followed by a phase that unifies labels by computing connected components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Moore Neighborhood tracing algorithm will do what you want. By definition, the Moore Neighborhood looks at 8-connectedness, but you should be able to easily adjust it to 4-connectedness. Your resulting regions will most likely be better if you test for 8-connectedness, but your application may have specific requirements.

Wikipedia has a good outline of the algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood). I've worked with this in the past and had great success--it's very fast.

Comment: thanks. the only problem with this approach is how to find a stating pixel. in my case I need to trace an outline of a region and it is not the only region in the image, so I cannot just scan the image starting at the corner.

Comment: If you start your iteration at the location of the user's mouse click, the resulting outline will be of the desired region. The general idea is that you walk from left to right until you hit a pixel of a different color. Upon finding such a pixel, you look at all neighbors in a clockwise direction and move to the first pixel that's part of the current region. Eventually you end up with an outline. You don't have to scan the image starting in the corner.

Comment: Suppose I click on a white pixel somewhere in the middle of the region (I want to outline a white region), and it has no black pixels (my background) in its neighbourhood. Then what do I do?

Comment: You start at your given location and walk from left to right until you hit a black pixel. When you hit that pixel, you begin the clockwise iterations. If the user clicks in the middle of a region, you first have to reach the edge before you can begin to define it.

Comment: Yes, I have to find an edge, and start there, the problem is that my region can contain holes. I am ok with ignoring these holes but I need to find the outline of the region that contains them. Finding an edge is not trivial it seems to me.

Comment: It's not trivial, but it isn't overly complicated either. You can extend the algorithm to do both a left and a right pass. Walk from left to right and trace an outline. Then walk from right to left and trace another outline if you have not already marked the pixel you hit. If the outlines don't match (i.e. the pixel you hit in the right->left direction is new), run another left and right pass. When your left and right passes trace the same outline, you know you have completely outlined the user's selected region. Note you'll have to compare multiple combinations, but it's only one pixel each.